# Object Oriented Bouncing Ball

Tags: javascript, oop

So it has been a good long while since I programmed in a functional language. I have this code functioning normally; however I dislike it due to my OOD preferences.

```
var canvasWidth = 900;
var canvasHeight = 200;

var canvas0;
var context0;
var x0 = 20;
var y0 = 20;
var dx0 = 4;
var dy0 = 4;

function draw() {
    context0.clearRect(0, 0, context0.canvas.width, context0.canvas.height);
    context0.beginPath();
    context0.fillStyle = "red";
    context0.arc(x0, y0, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context0.closePath();
    context0.fill();

    // Boundary Logic
    if (x0 < 13 || x0 > context0.canvas.width - 13) {
        dx0 = (-dx0);
    }
    if (y0 < 13 || y0 > context0.canvas.height - 13) {
        dy0 = (-dy0);
    }
    x0 += dx0;
    y0 += dy0;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    canvas0 = document.getElementById("gfxCanvas");
    context0 =  canvas0.getContext('2d');
    context0.canvas.width  = canvasWidth;
    context0.canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    setInterval(draw, 10);
}
```

I have tried to refactor it into more object oriented design but I am having problems with the graphics processing.  I can get the ball to appear once but I can not get it to move.  Here is my refactored code; be aware that it is in a mid point of refactoring so there are some clear errors due to random tinkering.

```
function Ball(x, y, r, color) {
    this.radius = r;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;  
    this.color = color;
    console.log("x in creation" + this.x);
    console.log("y in creation" + this.y);
    draw();

}
Ball.prototype.draw = function(){
    context1.beginPath();
    console.log("x in DRAW()" + this.x);
    console.log("y in DRAW()" + this.y);
    context1.fillStyle = this.color;
    context1.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context1.closePath();
    context1.fill();
};

Ball.prototype.move = function(dx, dy){
    // Boundary Logic
    if (this.x < 13 || this.x > context1.canvas.width - 13) {
        dx = (-dx);
    }
    if (this.y < 13 || this.y > context1.canvas.height - 13) {
        dy = (-dy);
    }

    this.x += dx;
    this.y += dy;

};

function initialize() {
    canvas1 = document.getElementById("gfxCanvas2");
    context1 =  canvas1.getContext('2d');
    context1.canvas.width  = 900;
    context1.canvas.height = 200;
    ball1 = new Ball(20,20,20, "red");
    setInterval(ball1.move(4,4), 10);
}
```

I would preferably like this method to be the movement method.  The actual method would take the direction/speed vectors.

`setInterval(ball1.move(4,4), 10);`

Comment: I suspect that `this` isn't what you think it is when `move` actually executes.

Comment: That is what I was suspecting hence I added some of the console.logs  I am still getting used to functional scope and closures.  I wonder if using a namespace type of object creation

Comment: In addition to the issue with your setinterval, you only ever call `draw` once and even in that call it should be `this.draw` as currently it will blow up saying `draw` is undefined.  You'll either need to call draw in your move function or in your setinterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval(ball1.move(4,4), 10);
```

This doesn't work the way you intended it: It calls `ball1.move(4,4)` once, then calls the result of that every 10ms. You want the `move` method to be called every 10ms instead, right? There are two ways to do that:

```
setInterval(function() {
  ball1.move(4,4);
}, 10);
```

or like this (more elegant in my opinion):

```
setInterval(ball1.move.bind(ball1,4,4), 10);
```

Comment: That is a good idea and one that i originally implemented.  However for the sake of focusing purely on the ball object i removed that aspect of the program.  I was unsure if a context is akin to a layer on the canvas.  Preferably I would like every ball object to be on its own context so when clearing the frame it clears only that balls context and not the others.

Comment: I will give this a try, but that is exactly what I saw going on but I was unsure how to resolve it.  I will incorporate this and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
setInterval(ball1.move.bind(ball1, 4, 4), 10);
```

That is equivalent of wrapping your call to `move` in an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() { ball1.move(4, 4); }, 10);
```

Then you will also need to update `move` so that it calls `draw` appropriately too.

In addition, I would not use a global variable to access the drawing context - even if I wasn't going to go completely OOP I would make sure that the `draw` method and the `move` method take a context (which, for the sake of simplicity could be "owned" by the ball).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, everyone.  You clarified everything very well and pointed me in the correct direction.  I suspected it was working in the manner you articulated however I wasn't entirely sure.  I knew a couple of things where wrong with my implementation but couldn't put it so succinctly with my current knowledge.

However, I discovered my problem which your solutions were remedying in a more direct manner.  I can't treat javascript with OOD paradigms.  I will be refactoring the code using a more functional design pattern.  Not attempting to coerce the code into a OO design will make things considerably easier.  Your solutions helped but the bounds checking code was the next problem I ran into.

I'l be working this into a module design pattern for the ball objects which should be much more suited for js scope/closures and procedural workflow.